# How can I change the images in a listvue, after it is created?

Tags: android, listview

I have created a program that reads in  a file from a server to construct a list view.  It then loads an image in the background.  Now the image is loaded into an imageview to make sure it works. How can I load the images into my listview imageview rows?

```
public class Welcome extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    // data to load from html file
    ArrayList<String> images;   
    ArrayList<String> Links;
    ArrayList<String> LinkName;
    ArrayList<String> Price;

    int y;
    ArrayList<String> ted;

    int i;



    String[] items={"CASUAL","DRESSES","CAREER","OUTWEAR","FOOTWEAR",
            "JEWELRY","ACCESSORIES"};
    private HttpClient client;
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // data read in can be from 1-10
        images=new ArrayList();
        Links=new ArrayList();
        LinkName=new ArrayList();
        Price=new ArrayList();  



        // load in arrays from a file on a web server
        Loaddata();     

        // create a listvue based on the data loaded from the server
    setListAdapter(new IconicAdapter(this));

        // load in biytmap
    download();
    } // end function

    class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        Activity context;

        IconicAdapter(Activity context) {
            super(context, R.layout.row, LinkName);

            this.context=context;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                                                ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);

            label.setText( LinkName.get(position) );
            return(row);
        }
    }   


    private void download(){
     new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>(){

       @Override
       protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         try {
           String uri = "http://www.besttechsolutions.biz/icon.png";
           HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
           HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
           return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
         if(image == null){
             Log.d("ted", "could not download image");
//             Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Download failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         else{
             // losd into ListView
    //       ImageView myimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);
    //       myimage.setImageBitmap(image);
         }
       }
     }.execute();
    }
```

Comment: You want to display image in each row with text like this [image text/label] ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(image == null){
             Log.d("ted", "could not download image");
             getAdapter().setImage(image);
             //refresh
             getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
```

And add the `setImage` method to your `IconicAdapter`:

```
public void setImage(image){
     this.image = image;
}
```

You will need a field `image` in your adapter that you should check in `getView` and set the `ImageView` with it in case `image!=null`.

Comment: Hi,I'm confuse. I have a iconicAdpter now and a getview methed that sets the label.  As of now, the getview gets called for each row and after getview has been called for each row the bitmap has been loaded.  I'm a beginner.

Comment: So what's the question? Have you tried my solution? getView will be called after getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();